# Is stdin.readline() atomic in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, stdin, atomic, python-multithreading

With commands like `cat big_file|python do.py`, if `do.py` build multiple threads, and threads read data from stdin, do I need to use `threading.Lock()` to call `stdin.readline`?
Like:

```
with lock:
    line = stdin.readline()
do...
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for file object and the `readline` method? Does it mention any kind of thread-safety? Hence...

Comment: I read the python doc about sys.stdin. and haven't see something about atomic ,so I don't  know if stdin.readline() is thread-safety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPython's file API [explicitly locks the file object](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4caa695af94c/Objects/fileobject.c#l1433) around `readline` and other calls, which means `readline()` is indeed thread-safe. This mimics the historic behavior of C (POSIX) stdio which served as the basic of Python's file IO, and is not likely to change. Be warned, however, that this is not explicitly documented, so it could not be the case on other Python implementations, such as Jython or PyPy.

Comment: Thanks very much. by the way,How do you exactly find the related code in cpython? Could you teach me ? Thanks Again!

Comment: @kkerneo The sources contain an `Objects/` directory which defines built-in types, a `Modules/` directory that contains stdlib modules written in C and a `Lib/` directory that contains other pure-python stdlib modules. There's also a `Python/` directory that contains the core definitions of the interpreter. You can browse the repository online [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/03d6661c13a0).

Comment: Btw: this answer is technically incorrect. You are just showing that the operation is *thread-safe*, not that it is *atomic*! In fact you can see from the source code that signal handlers *can* be run during a call to `readline` if an error occurs. These handlers could make other calls to the file object and see the modified state. Atomicity means that either the read is completely performed or it doesn't do anything, but this is not the case since some code *could* see the object in a "partial read state" in certain circumstances.

Comment: Yea, this is a good method.but it's also a little difficult for me locate the exact code.I'll lean to use this method, thanks!

Comment: @Bakuriu Right, I forgot about signal handlers. I've now changed *atomic* to *thread-safe*.

Answer (score 2):

You may be better off using an architecture in which a single dedicated thread reads lines from `sys.stdin` (or other file) and places them on a [`Queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue) object. Worker threads then get lines from the Queue which is inherently thread safe.

The file locking mentioned in another answer is present only if the underlying OS supports it (via `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()`), otherwise it is a no-op. Furthermore, different python implementations might implement it differently.

`Queue.Queue` provides consistent behaviour across all OSes and implementations. Another advantage is that you can easily move to the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module which provides a compatible [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) implementation. This allows you to move your threads into separate processes which might provide performance benefits on multiple processor systems.